# How to create Unit / NUnit / XUnit Tests for a Visual Studio Extension projects (VSIX) using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

On VS 2015 you can test your VSIX projects using XUnit / NUnit / Basic Unit Tests from Visual Studio. Unfortunately, this way is not possible anymore in VS 2017 and VS 2019. Some attributes are now deprecated and I cannot find a replacement for them.

`HostType` attribute does not launch an instance of Visual Studio because it is deprecated, and I cannot find any proper information about how to properly launch and test an extension.

At this moment I am trying to find a way to test my VS Extensions using Visual Studio 2017. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What attributes are deprecated? Are you getting any other error messages when you build?

Comment: `HostType` attribute does not launch an instance of Visual Studio because it is deprecated, and I cannot find any proper information about how to properly launch and test an extension. There are no errors, but unfortunately, there is no VS instance too.

Comment: In Vs2015, the [hosttype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.hosttypeattribute.hosttype?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) works well since this attribute class is defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll(MSTest v1 framework), and mstestv1 is supported in vs2015. But in vs2017, it uses MSTestv2, this attribute is not defined in it. Maybe you can try [TestHost](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudio-TestHost), hope it works. And for the feature to test vsix, maybe you can consider user voice.